# javascript:regular expression for this

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me to find the regular expression for this using javascript.

```
<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec3</div>

<div class="fs" id="a_secret">51drdsf3</div>

<div class="fs" id="a_secret">54451drwec3</div>
```

I need to retrieve **71drwec3** , **51drdsf3** from the above expression

or any other characters other than 71drwec3

Comment: What parts of the string are constant and which are variable?

Comment: I am assuming this is on an html page, why cant you just access it with the dom selector or jquery?

Comment: don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @cwolves . I don't think that what he wants.

Comment: @AndreasAL, that's the point. A bad question gets a bad answer.

Comment: my net went down ,,,so i was unable to reply

Answer (score 2):

`/(<([^>]+)>)/ig`

```
var myString = '<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec3</div>',
    strippedString = myString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

alert(strippedString); // 71drwec3
```

Using jQuery:

```
var myString = '<div class="fs" id="a_secret">71drwec3</div>';

alert( $(myString).text() );
```

Comment: I think you missed the call to `.replace()` in your first example.

Comment: i get a error...mystring is not a function

Comment: @gill3 Thanks i have changes.